# Converting a video from VOB to AVI while making the file smaller

Tags: windows-xp, video, conversion, video-encoding

How do I convert a video from one format, in this case a **.vob** into another, say **.avi**?

I have a DVD of 4.2 GB and would like to convert that to a smaller filesize and different format of an .avi file of around 700 MB.

I'm working on a Windows XP machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm very happy with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.  [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is another good option.

Comment: What is the average speed when you are converting with Handbrake? I'm converting .vob (4,2 GB) to .avi. What should be the size of .avi and the average speed while converting?

Answer (score 7):

For video conversion of all types, the common favourite is [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). Not only will it support most filetypes (it even has nice presets for common media players, such as iPod, PSP, Apple TV etc), it is available for most platforms.

[image]

Comment: Is this wrong? Why the down vote?

Comment: I'm assuming someone ignorant saw a Mac screenshot and thought you didn't realize the part about Windows XP in the original question, even though handbrake has Windows builds.

Comment: I hate the fact that no one bothers explaining why they downvote. It drives me crazy.

Comment: I hate the fact I take down votes so seriously

Answer (score 4):

The gold standard in video encoding/conversion is two tools:

[FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/).

If they can't do it, it probably can't be done. Most of the GUI tools around are based on one of these two libraries (in fact MEncoder is itself partly based on FFMpeg). They both support decoding encoding and recoding pretty much every video format under the sun. They are also both open source and free and have been ported to most platforms (including xp).

The disadvantage is that they are both command line tools and have a learning curve about as steep as a mile high concrete wall, so they don't really fit your "something that beginners can easily use" requirement. I Thought I'd post them here in case you wanted to do something a bit more specific. (The MEncoder website does have a list of GUI front ends for various tasks.)

Answer (score 3):

[Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/) is one of the best:

1. Supports converting all popular video,audio,picture formats to others
2. Repair damaged video and audio file
3. Reducing Multimedia file size
4. Support iPhone and iPod multimedia file formats
5. Picture converting supports Zoom, Rotate/Flip, tags
6. DVD Ripper.
7. Supports 50 languages

[image]

Comment: Could the down-voter please leave a comment as to why.

Comment: I'm giving you +1 because of No 7, it contains my language :)

Comment: Hvala :) Thank you and others, now I have work for few days to see which one is the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) will convert/resize VOB files into pretty much any format of your choice (incl. AVI).

> Input Video format: 3gp, 3g2, amv,
>   asf, avi, dat, dvr-ms, fli, flc, flv,
>   m2ts, mpg, mkv, mov, m4v, mp4, nsv,
>   ogm, qt, rm(vb), str, swf, ts, trp,
>   ty, ty+, tmf, viv, **vob**, wmv

Comment: I'm unable to download with this link, are you sure about it?

Comment: sorry about that, edited the post. while the link was correct, it doesn't work this way. you'll have to find the way to the download link youself, it's 3 clicks from the home page (1. Start downloading super, 2. download and use, 3. Download Super setup file). what were they thinking? :)

Answer (score 2):

Give [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) a try, it's a nice GUI approach which uses FFMPEG as the backend.

Answer (score 2):

[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) is one of the best GUI front-ends to FFMpeg for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This one i have used for years, simple to use

[FLV to AVI MPEG WMV 3GP MP4 iPod Convert](http://www.tucows.com/preview/513034)

It says flv to ...... But it can convert any file to any format and specific sizes to match mp3 players etc

Answer (score 1):

Try [AutoGK](http://www.autogk.me.uk/)... An automated [gordian knot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gordianknot/), the best dvd ripper/video compressor out there...

Comment: I can't download from this 'gordian knot' link, Windows Explorer keeps shutting me, and the first link has too many options to download, which one is the best?

Comment: Direct link for GK: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gordianknot/Gordian%20Knot%20Rip%20Pack/GK%20Rippack%200.35.0%20-%20pack2/GordianKnot.RipPack.0.35.0.Setup.2.exe?use_mirror=sunet
Direct link for Auto GK: http://www.autogk.me.uk/index.php?name=Downloads&d_op=getit&lid=2

Sorry: i'm not able in using html for hiding the whole http address.